# Пропал весь код из класса в android studio

Tags: java, android-sdk, android-studio

При работе завис android studio, поэтому я завершил его работу через диспетчер задач. Но после того как я его заново запустил, весь у двух классов, которые были активны перед закрытием пропал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открыл эти же файлы отдельно через редактор он в место кода показывает вот, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто нибудь знает, как восстановить исходники?

Comment: знаем: надо пользоваться системой контроля версий (git/svn и прочее)

Comment: Я так понимаю им надо было пользоваться пока еще не пропал код?

Comment: да, и комитить почаще. Тогда если что-то вдруг куда-то пропало, можно было бы откатиться на недавнюю версию и вы потеряли бы лишь небольшую часть своих изменений. К тому же - если на каком-то этапе вы вдруг сделали что-нибудь плохое, можно было бы откатиться назад и получить работающий код до этих "плохих" изменений. Особенно полезно этим пользоваться, когда разработкой занимается несколько человек.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за совет

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попробовать восстановить содержимое файла из локальной истории изменений (аналог системы контроля версий): VCS | Local history | Show history.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, но увы и там ничего не осталось. Придется заново писать более 2000 строчек (